# How to sum two different fields from two tables with one field is common

Tags: sql, oracle, aggregate-functions

I have two tables `Sales` and `Charges`.

Tables having data as:

```
  'Sales'                                     'Charges'
SID    F_AMT                           SID            C_AMT
1       100                            1               10
1       100                            1               10
1       100                            1               20
1       200                            2               20
2       200                            2               10
2       300                            3               20
4       300                            3               30
4       300                            3               10
4       300                            5               20
4       200                            5               10
```

I want the output as below:

```
SID       Total_Fees     Total_charges
1           500              40
2           500              30
3            0               60
4           1100             0
5            0               30
```

Comment: what have you tried with your own?

Comment: So you want us to write the query for you so you don't have too?

Comment: I would first find the totals for each table (you know how to do that, right? Hint: SUM() and GROUP BY), and then I would do a full outer join of both queries.

Comment: I was trying with below code....

Select Sid
            , Sum(f_amt) as total_fees
            , Sum(c_amt) as total_charges
From ( select sid, f_amt
              From sales
              Union all
              select sid, c_amt
              From charges
          )
Group by sid

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to do it for the whole tables this is the simplest approach:

```
Select Sid
            , Sum(f_amt) as total_fees
            , Sum(c_amt) as total_charges
From ( select sid, f_amt, 0 as c_amt
              From sales
              Union all
              select sid, 0 as f_amt, c_amt
              From charges
          )
Group by sid
```

Comment: thank you so much for helping me. I was not aware about the below approach..

select sid, f_amt, 0 as c_amt
              From sales
              Union all
              select sid, 0 as f_amt, c_amt
              From charges

Comment: If this answer has proved helpful you should consider upvoting or accepting it. Accepted answers improve StackOverflow as a rsource for future Seekers.

Answer (score 1):

Use `full join` and `nvl()`:

```
select sid, nvl(sum(f_amt), 0) fees, nvl(sum(c_amt), 0) charges
  from sales s 
  full join charges c using (sid)
  group by sid 
  order by sid
```

Demo:

```
with sales(sid, f_amt) as (
    select 1, 100 from dual union all select 1, 100 from dual union all 
    select 1, 100 from dual union all select 1, 200 from dual union all 
    select 2, 200 from dual union all select 2, 300 from dual union all 
    select 4, 300 from dual union all select 4, 300 from dual union all 
    select 4, 300 from dual union all select 4, 200 from dual ),
charges (sid, c_amt) as (
    select 1, 10 from dual union all select 1, 10 from dual union all
    select 1, 20 from dual union all select 2, 20 from dual union all
    select 2, 10 from dual union all select 3, 20 from dual union all
    select 3, 30 from dual union all select 3, 10 from dual union all
    select 5, 20 from dual union all select 5, 10 from dual )
select sid, nvl(sum(f_amt), 0) fees, nvl(sum(c_amt), 0) charges
  from sales s 
  full join charges c using (sid)
  group by sid 
  order by sid
```

Output:

```
   SID       FEES    CHARGES
------ ---------- ----------
     1       1500        160
     2       1000         60
     3          0         60
     4       1100          0
     5          0         30
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT SID,
      COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN t=1 THEN AMT END),0) AS Total_Fees,
      COALESCE(SUM(CASE WHEN t=2 THEN AMT END),0) AS Total_Charges
FROM (SELECT SID, F_AMT AS AMT, 1 AS t
      FROM Sales
      UNION ALL
      SELECT SID, C_AMT AS AMT, 2 AS t
      FROM Charges) sub
GROUP BY SID
ORDER BY SID;
```

**[DB Fiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=48ede0420e541d542304d21b602cb2fa)**